# Proguard returned with error code 1 android parse.com

Tags: android, proguard

I want to apply proguard to my application, but following errors are generated.

```
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1:        can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.lnsur.kdbqq193162.MV$6: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class com.lnsur.kdbqq193162.MV
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-08-26 17:53:15 - Music And Videos] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
```

Following libraries are used

[image]

My proguard-project.txt file:

```
-libraryjars /libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/com-lnsur-kdbqq193162.jar
-libraryjars /libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar
-libraryjars /libs/commons.io_2.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/ia-sdk-lib-5.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/Parse-1.5.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/simple-4.1.11.jar
-libraryjars /libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar
-dontwarn com.parse.**
```

I don't know how to solve it, so please help me, any suggestion related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arash is right

but you need to add more

try to add

```
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
 -dontwarn com.lnsur.kdbqq193162.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```